# Socket IO scaling: is it more efficient to send messages to specific socket id's?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am developing an application using Socket IO that needs to be scaled across multiple servers. This is being achieved through socket.io-redis, which essentially interconnects all of my servers running socket IO and treats Redis as a datastore that all of my servers/nodes running Socket IO publish messages from.

For better context, here is a diagram from MSDN that outlines my setup:

[image: socketio setup]

Here's my issue:

If Client A sends a message only intended for Client C to receive, I feel it's a waste of bandwidth to publish a message to Client B and D. My idea is that I would, on the server-side, record user id's and their corresponding open socket id's. Then when a client sends a message, I would do do a lookup and find a user's socket id(s) and publish the messages. This seems fine and dandy as well as heavily reliant on a robust system to keep that table of user id's and socket id's up to date, but there are two questions I have about implementing this system:

1) Is it more memory efficient to emit messages to only relevant socket id's, rather than to an entire channel across every server? I realize that with 4 total clients, this problem is very small, but imagine if I had 2000 concurrent users across 2 servers. If 1 client sends a message intended for 2 clients, I imagine sending a message to 1997 other clients is more taxing than sending to just those 2 socket id's, unless "io.sockets.connected[socket_id].emit" is not efficient. Example below:

```
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
});
```

vs.

```
for (i = 0; i < relevant_sockets.length; i++) { 
    io.sockets.connected[relevant_sockets[i]].emit('chat message', msg);
}
```

2) Since I'm using multiple servers, are socket id's guaranteed to be unique? I'm hoping the redis module is handling this since it's entire purpose is to link processes and servers, but I just want to be sure.

Thanks ahead of time for any help.

Answer (score 0):

1) What you suggest is pretty common practice. You'll save a little bit on memory, but the biggest gain will be CPU and response times under load.

2) The id assigned to each socket looks to be a randomly generated id. Taking a look at the source code for socket.io-redis, there does not seem to be anything that ensures that each id is unique. If you are concerned about ids not being unique, you could generate your own unique id and store it along side the socket id. Then you'd just use both id's as the keys for your lookup (perhaps even create a hash out of them).

Comment: Thanks for the great information. My main concern about unique socket ID's is in regards to security. If two clients can potentially have the same socket ID, how can I make sure not to send the wrong client a message that is not intended for them?

Comment: I mean, there's really no magic solution or trick to this. You can either trust the random generator and not worry about the possibility of a ID collision, or you can write a routine to verify that each id is in fact unique. This is a really broad subject in computing in general. Many large complicated systems rely on UUID's, which are randomly generated, but may theoretically have a collision. If I were you, I'd not worry about it, and trust the unique ID generator.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely do **not** want to broadcast messages to all clients when you need to send it to only one. Your approach #1 is like operating in "god mode", perhaps intended only for the administrator.

I have implemented a similar architecture to yours. However, I also use Redis to map my client ID's (the client names) to the socket id AND vice-versa. For example, you can join in as "omegalen" with socket id 123. Then you disconnect, for some reason, and you get a new socket id: 456. When I need to send a message to "omegalen", I need to first lookup "omegalen" in Redis and get your most recent socket id: 456, as 123 is gone and it will not work. Here's some sample code to give an idea. Notice I prefix my keys with a namespace and I also set an expiration time to them (24 hours):

```
var client = redis.createClient(redisPort, redisHost);

function _updateSocketId(clientName, socketId) {
    client.set("client/" + clientName, socketId);
    client.set("socket/" + socketId, clientName);

    client.expire("client/" + clientName, 1 * 24 * 60 * 60); //in seconds. 1 day
    client.expire("socket/" + socketId, 1 * 24 * 60 * 60); //in seconds. 1 day
}

function _getSocketId(clientName, callback) {
    //all clients are stored and prefixed with the namespace below
    client.get("client/" + clientName, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            callback("Error retrieving key for " + clientName + "Error: " + err, null);
            return;
        }
        var socketId = data;
        logger.debug("Retrieved socket for client/" + clientName + ". Socket id: " + socketId);
        callback(null, socketId);

    });
}

function _findClientBySocket(socketId) {
    var name = client.get("socket/" + socketId);
    return name;
}

function _deleteSocketId(socketId, clientName) {
    logger.debug("deleting socket: " + socketId + " - clientName: " + clientName);
    client.del("socket/" + socketId);
    client.del("client/" + clientName);
}

module.exports.getSocketId = _getSocketId;
```

Then, when setting up my websocket server I listen for events and update the client / socket id map accordingly:

```
socket.on("join", function (clientName, callback) {
    //update Redis with new client id / socket id
    redisUtil.updateSocketId(clientName, socket.client.id);
})

socket.on("rejoin", function (clientName) {
    redisUtil.updateSocketId(clientName, socket.client.id);
})

socket.on("disconnect", function (clientName) {
    redisUtil.deleteSocketId(socket.client.id, clientName);
})
```

The code above is just a sample code to give you an idea, as it can also be easily enhanced to handle multiple sockets per client (say you have two browser clients open). Your architectural diagram is good and it'll work, but you need to emit messages only to the intended clients.

I don't want to get off topic, but you can also use namespaces in socket.io and emit events to a group of users, say, only to a special type of clients:

```
 var ssClients = io.of("/ssClients");  //socket.io namespace for the some ss clients
ssClients.on("connection", function (socket) {
..
```

This wasn't part of your question, but I think it's valuable to mention in case you need to broadcast / filter messages by namespace.

As far as the socket.io id's being unique, I never had this problem. Google implemented a similar architecture in a MASSIVE scale and they didn't run into problems. You can read it [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/real-time-gaming-with-node-js-websocket?hl=en).

I hope this helps; overall your architecture is very good!